# module outside of src/app folder giving error in angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I'm working in an *angular project using Visual Studio IDE*. I'm getting the error message in console window as shown [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l3o21oVT8b2husUpZqvlhkT4-dUTL8Je), if I put my module(named as fw) outside the src/app folder as shown [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fB6jYzLwnpMICXFVzqcR5WsfQFQPK2-o). But, If I put my module inside the src/app folder as [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rlX5jxmHmOYWsFtSjahoxxKezNe5JoyN), then no issue..What may be the reason?Can anyone help me out..

Comment: can you attach screen shots in question itself? it will be helpful to answer your questions easily.

Comment: I will paste the error in console window here below

Comment: Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56536/src/fw/fw.module